# SOLVE function better solution

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where a lot of cells are multiplied with a CONSTANT value and added and the result (SOLL) differs  from the expected (IST) value and the only way I was able to find, was to make 10 iterations modifying each time the CONSTANT value till the SOLL and IST are pretty equal.
My method looks too stupid and I am just asking a beautiful and intelligent way to solve it...

thanks

```
function costante() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //spreadsheet "options"
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); //sheet nr.1
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ 

var dataRange = sheet.getRange("o5:o5");    //marge ist
var mist = dataRange.getValues();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange("o4:o4");    //marge soll
var msoll = dataRange.getValues();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange("n1:n1");    //costante
var costante = dataRange.getValues();  
var minus = 1;

if(mist - msoll < 0) { minus = -1};
costante = mist / msoll * minus * costante;
sheet.getRange("n1:n1").setValues([[costante]]);}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want, assuming your "lot of cells" are in A1:A10 and the `IST` value is in E1 is:

```
=E1/sum(A1:A10)
```

but please note the tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-spreadsheet/info).

Answer (score 0):

thanks, I was first surprised by the simple method  and I checked it:

10  values and their addition gives for instance = 10     (sum(a1:a10))
the IST value that I would like to have is 500    (E1)

E1/sum(A1:A10) =  500/10 = 50 = C  (COSTANTE)

E1 = Sum(A1:A10) x C

if I multiply each A(y) value with 50, I have 500 and the proposed formula would perfectly work

BUT I forgot to mention that the values of A(y) are formulas that include already my COSTANTE  it means that in reality each A(y) value is a formula that contains C

E1 = Sum( A(y) x C )  x C

a) for that reason the solution proposed does not give the needed value, and I was obliged to repeat the calculation  ca.10 times

b) I also added a delay of 1 second because I was not sure if the spreadsheet is able to calculate so fast  (please tell me if it is necessary)

c) and I said that if the result is +/- 2  from expected value, to stop to calculate

It works but is still not beautiful...

```
function costante() 
 {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   //spreadsheet "options"
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); //sheet nr.1
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange("o5:o5");    //marge ist
   var mist = dataRange.getValues();

   for(var i=0; i<20; i++)
     {

   var dataRange = sheet.getRange("o4:o4");    //marge soll
   var msoll = dataRange.getValues();

   var dataRange = sheet.getRange("n1:n1");    //costante
   var costante = dataRange.getValues();   
   var diff = msoll - mist;

    if(diff < -2) { costante = costante * 1.005;}

    else if (diff > 2) { costante = costante * 0.995;}

    else  {return;}

    sheet.getRange("n1:n1").setValues([[costante]]);
    Utilities.sleep(1000);                                          //wait 1.5sec
      }                                              
   }
```